# Is there a word for something that does NOT belong to someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

We use *owned* to denote something that we possess or that belongs to someone. What can we call things that do *not* belong to someone?

[**Editor's note**: I can't tell whether the asker wants a word for something that a specific person does not own, or a word for something that nobody owns.]

Comment: Not bad,that was quite a Gouda pun!!

Comment: :groans and begs for mercy:

Comment: @cindi, @ArthurRex: THWACKS all around.

Comment: Duck with a lisp: thwack,thwack....afthwack,afthwack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for something not owned by someone you say "not his."
Example:

> The bicycle is not Joe's.

For something that doesn't belong to anyone, I would use "ownerless."
Example:

> The stray dog is ownerless

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the word ownerless. But don't know how to ask that as a question

Comment: Just out of curiosity, were you trying to translate the Hebrew word הפקר? That's the only way I've ever used the word "ownerless in English.

Answer (score 4):

For intellectual property, you can say: It is in the **public domain** (not covered by copyright and hence belongs to no one)

Comment: And the concept also applies to, eg, land which is somehow held in common.

Answer (score 3):

Something can be **unclaimed** or **abandoned** property.

Answer (score 2):

The word "unowned" exists, but it usually means "not owned by anybody" as opposed to "not owned by a particular person".

So "This bike is unowned by me" is possible, but unusual. "A sale of unowned property" is perhaps more likely.

In some software systems, items may have owners (whatever that might mean in that system), and we could talk about an "unowned item" there.

Answer (score 2):

[Ownerless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ownerless).

Comment: I am assuming the extra periods are because of the character limit. See the [discussion on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/836/exception-to-30-character-minimum-for-answers) for the _appropriate_ way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly, you can  say "not owned".

I own a bike → This bike is **owned** by me. (This bike is mine.)

I don't own a bike → This bike is **not owned** by me. (This bike is not mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Humans (and animals) that do not belong to someone or something are often called **free**. Objects that do not belong to anyone can also be seen as free (for the taking).

Answer (score 0):

If shared among a group, something can be considered to be *communal property*.

> In the town, bicycles are considered
>   communal property: you simply take one
>   from the designated rack and leave it
>   in the corresponding rack at the destination.