# How do you say in English to "Declare something ownerless"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the act of making something ownerless?

All I've seen is to "declare something ownerless".

However, in this statement one isn't so much as announcing as he is transferring something property. Moreover, if one wants to discuss his act of transferring, it wouldn't make sense to use the word "declare" (i.e "his declaration of making this item ownerless was ineffective" sounds like a mouthful).

Comment: Both Monica Cello's and Gnawme's answers are good for the idea of giving up a claim that you have. But neither addresses the idea of asserting that property that you never had a claim to is, in fact, ownerless. This might mean challenging someone else's claim, or someone in authority, a judge, for example, declaring that there is no valid ownership on record. I'm not sure which the poster is looking for and if the latter, I don't have an answer, just pointing out that the existing answers may be incomplete.

Comment: Possibly related: _[Is there a word for something that does NOT belong to someone?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17707/5822)_

Comment: Perhaps "disown" is the word you're looking for?

Comment: @jay The question is about property that you **did** own but you know want to ?disown?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A word that says it all is *renounce*:

> **renounce**, *verb* : to announce one's abandonment of the ownership of : give up, abandon, or resign usually formally (something
>   possessed) [MW]

Answer (score 7):

You can *abandon* something (or your claim on something) or *release* something into the public domain (moreso with IP than physical items).

Answer (score 2):

Slaves can be *freed* by their "owners."

> verb ( **frees** |friz|, **[freed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/free?q=freed#free__23)** |frid|, **freeing** |friɪŋ|) [ trans. ]
>   make free, in particular
>
> • from captivity, confinement, or slavery : they were freed from jail.

Comment: And *emancipate* is a more legalistic word for this.